# LocalReport rendering in an Azure Web Job

Tags: c#, azure, reporting, webjob, localreport

I have an MVC web application running in Azure.  We are using instances of `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport` to run reports against the database that the web application is using.  Some of the data sets are very large and rendering can take a very long time.  So we decided to offload the rendering of the reports into a separate App Service as a Web Job.  The application runs correctly in my development environment, but when it is uploaded as a web job, it crashes with the following exception in the web job logs:

```
[10/30/2017 17:16:48 > 81a023: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report '' is invalid. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatVersion' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
[10/30/2017 17:16:48 > 81a023: ERR ]    at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
[10/30/2017 17:16:48 > 81a023: ERR ]    at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
[10/30/2017 17:16:48 > 81a023: ERR ]    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
[10/30/2017 17:16:48 > 81a023: ERR ]    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
[10/30/2017 17:16:48 > 81a023: ERR ]    at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetFullPathWithAssert(String fileName)
[10/30/2017 17:16:48 > 81a023: ERR ]    at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
[10/30/2017 17:16:48 > 81a023: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatVersion.<>c__DisplayClass1.<.cctor>b__0()
[10/30/2017 17:16:48 > 81a023: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.RevertImpersonationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Run>b__0(Object state)
[10/30/2017 17:16:48 > 81a023: ERR ]    at System.Security.SecurityContext.Run(SecurityContext securityContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[10/30/2017 17:16:48 > 81a023: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.RevertImpersonationContext.Run(ContextBody callback)
[10/30/2017 17:16:48 > 81a023: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatVersion..cctor()
```

The error is thrown when the `LocalReport.Render()` method is called.

The report definitions are read from a table in the database so that nothing needs to be re-compiled or re-published if a change needs to be made to the report.

My question is, why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException:

According to Azure [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sqlclassic/virtual-machines-windows-classic-sql-server-reportviewer?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Fclassic%2Ftoc.json), reportViewer configured in local processing mode is not supported in Microsoft Azure.

> ReportViewer configured in local processing mode is not supported in Microsoft Azure
>
> My question is, why is this happening and how do I fix it?

As Azure WebApp is a [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox), if Cloudservice is acceptable, please have try to use Cloudservice. About how to Migrate and Publish a Web Application to an Azure Cloud Service from Visual Studio, we could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service).